# Thriller Horror manga with explicit themes. Female protagonist has a bird that becomes male

Tags: story-identification, manga

This was a thriller/horror manga. It involves a girl, she has powers and she has a friend that's actually her bird. It becomes male later on.

It's very graphic. I remember the girl peeing because she was excited or scared in one panel. The art is very disturbing and so is the the story

I read this before 2018.

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What powers? And what does "she has a friend that's actually her bird. It becomes male later on." mean?

Comment: What kind of bird?

Comment: Probably like a small sparrow.

Comment: A bird that's actually a Boy/male